# Keep the notification alive a bit longer?

Tags: html, notifications, html5-notifications

Currently using the HTML5 Notification API, it works like a charm. Except that I want the Notification to stay at least 10 seconds, because there is quite some text inside it.

I read something about recreating periodically the notification when it is destroyed and it was not a user input (for exemple, the notification is destroyed because of the timeout, BAM, resend). Though it seems a bit overkill for what I want to do and a bit hackish too. Is there a simple way to keep my notification alive for a few more seconds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no way to achieve such a goal, at least for Firefox and Safari. That's part of the implementation of the standard which defines Notification API. Although on Chrome it is possible because Chrome doesn't close automatically the notification so you have to declare a timeout to close it. This timeout can be as long as you want.

Seems like the Notification API could be improved though.

Comment: MDN claims that this is on the operating system level.

Comment: At the time, it was browser dependent, at least for chrome. Do you have a link about that ?

Comment: [Note: Firefox and Safari close notifications automatically after a few moments (around four seconds). This may also happen at the operating system level.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications#Creating_a_notification)